# Azure OIDC IdP Initiated Logout

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, idp

A scenario is, user SSO logs into my system via Azure OIDC.  They are now logged into the IdP and my system.  While logged into my system, they open another tab and log out of the IdP.  They are now logged out of the IdP, but still logged into my system.

Does Azure support a way to let my system know that the user has logged out, that way I can log them out of my system?

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to clear your app's cookies or storage besides calling the Azure AD `end_session_endpoint`. This can be done using upon redirecting to the passed [`post_logout_redirect_uri`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request)

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to figure out how to handle IdP initiated logouts, not initiating logging out of the IdP.

Comment: If you want to to logout of all other applications then you need to register a LogoutUrl for each so that Azure AD sends an HTTP GET request to all of them. Applications must respond to this request by clearing any session that identifies the user and returning a 200 response.

Comment: So, my application would have a GET endpoint sitting out there that would log the user out of my domain, if hit.  Every Azure AD client that installs my application would need to register this endpoint (ex: https://myapp.com/idplogout) LogoutUrl for IdP initiated logout to work for them, correct?  Where do they register it?  I am looking at my test client and I see Redirect URIs and Front-channel logout URL, but neither of those look to be what you are talking about.